# redux - how to [ref] select in [mapDispatchToProps]

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, ref, setstate

redux - how to [ref] select in [mapDispatchToProps]

I'm currently working on [react] using [redux], but I don't know how to get [refs] from [mapDispatchToProps] inside [component].

my component event function code

```
this.webrtc.attachStream(stream ,this.remoteVideos[peer.id]);
```

my component render code

```
<video ref={(v) => this.remoteVideos[data.id] = v} playsInline />
```

container code(mapDispatchToProps)

```
rtc.on('videoAdded', (stream, peer) => {
   dispatch({
      type : ADD_MEDIA ,
      peer,
      stream
    });
 })
```

The code I'm trying to do

```
rtc.on('videoAdded', (stream, peer) => {
   dispatch({
      type : ADD_MEDIA ,
      peer,
      stream : rtc.attachStream(stream ,this.remoteVideos[peer.id]);
    });
 })
```

but fail.. code 
I must select [ref] from within [mapDispatchToProps] called [this.remoteVideos]

When I asked the question, I turned the translator around and asked the question. I'm sorry the sentence isn't smooth. I turned the translator.

Comment: Can you explain better what's your problem?

Comment: You mean your current program using setState and without Redux, and you wish to implement Redux into your program?

Comment: Added description.